# Guzzle 6.2 deperecated warning

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle

The following code gives me a

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri::resolve is deprecated since version 1.4. Use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\UriResolver::resolve instead.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://api.geonames.org/countryCodeXML']);
$options = ['query' => ['lat' => 50, 'lng' => 14, 'username' => 'demo']];
echo $client->get('countryCodeXML', $options)->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: Why downvote? OP does not explicitly calling the `Uri::resolve()` method, so this may point to an unexpected behaviour of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand anyone downvotes this question.

You should open new issues in GitHub instead of being asking on StackOverflow.

Link reference: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1759.

Version 6.2.3 has been released with the patch.

I think you should update to latest version.

or:

For workaround, we added line `"guzzlehttp/psr7":"1.4.0"` to composer.json temporarily